# How to expose methods of a property object as if they are objects own methods? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a really big urge to do something like this:

```
class A {
    constructor(){}
    age() { return 15; }
}

class B {
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A();
    // DO SOMETHING THAT THIS IS POSSIBLE:
    }
}

B b = new B();
b.age();
```

How to expose the method as if it was object `b`'s own method? I need to do this for every method of a property, regardless of number and name.

NOTE: I can't use inheritance.

Comment: `Inheritance` is a keyword.

Comment: @Oen44 I added a note. I can't use inheritance.

Comment: @Oen44 Is there a way to combine the prototypes somehow? To expose the method `age` on the object `b`?

Comment: @StudioKonKon Then it's pointless to create class B. It will work as Class A. Any methods that class B is using won't work.

Comment: Why can't you use inheritance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties Maybe this can help?

Comment: It should be more than a note to the reason why you cannot use inheritance, please expand on the reasons why you believe you cannot use and if possible, please give a sample of your code where you want to use it

Answer (score 3):

`extends` provides inheritance functionality:

```js
class A {
  constructor(){}
  age() { return 15; }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}

const b = new B();

console.log(b.age());
```

I'd be interested to learn why you can't use normal inheritance. Here's a way to manually inherit from a base class:

```js
class A {
  constructor(){}
  age() { return 15; }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype).forEach(prop => {
      if (prop !== 'constructor') {
        this[prop] = A.prototype[prop];
      }
    });
  }
}

const b = new B();

console.log(b.age());
```

Comment: `NOTE: I can't use inheritance.`

Comment: You didn't even read the entire question... No inheritance. I can't use it in this situation because of other reasons.

Comment: What are the reasons?

Comment: I updated my answer with a different method. I's be curious to hear why you can't use regular inheritance

Answer (score 3):

I would try implementing `B` as a `Proxy`.

```
class A {
    constructor(){}
    age() { return 15; }
}

const b = new Proxy(new A(), {
    get: function(object, property) {
        if (typeof object[property] === 'function') {
            return object.property();
        }
    }
    set: function(object, property) {}
}
```

You can read into it more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).